# Converting System Date Format to Date Format Acceptable to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How can I convert a system date format (like 3/18/2014) to the format readable in DateTime? 
I wanted to get the total days from two dates, which will come from two TextBoxes.

I have tried this syntax:

```
DateTime tempDateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse(txtDateBorrowed.Text);
DateTime tempReturnDate = DateTime.Parse(txtReturnDate.Text);
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Today - tempDateBorrowed;
rf.txtDaysBorrowed.Text = span.ToString();
```

But `tempDateBorrowed` always returns the minimum date for a `DateTime` varibale. I think this is because DateTime does not properly parse my system date format. As a consequence, it incorrectly displays the number of days. For example, if I try to enter 3/17/2014 and 3/18/2014 respectively, I always get -365241 days instead of 1.

Edit: I wanted my locale to be non-specific so I did not set a specific locale for my date format. (My system format by the way is en-US)

Comment: Please consider to update your post with information about current culture (something like "en-us", "fr-fr", ...) at the moment of the call - parsing depends on it. You also may remove unrelated lines from sample - just one line `DateTime.Parse("12121212", new CultureInfo("en-us"));` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DateTime.ParseExact` method instead.

See following sample code (I've used strings instead of TextBoxes since I used a Console app to write this code). Hope this helps.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string txtDateBorrowed = "3/17/2014";
            string txtReturnDate = "3/18/2014";
            string txtDaysBorrowed = string.Empty;

            DateTime tempDateBorrowed = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateBorrowed, "M/d/yyyy", null);
            DateTime tempReturnDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtReturnDate, "M/d/yyyy", null);
            TimeSpan span = DateTime.Today - tempDateBorrowed;
            txtDaysBorrowed = span.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And, null in the ParseExact method means the current culture

Answer (score 1):

ToString is not Days

[TimeSpan.TotalDays Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the format of the datetime in the textboxes like this

```
DateTime tempDateBorrowed = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateBorrowed.Text.Trim(), "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime tempReturnDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtReturnDate.Text.Trim(), "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also you may have to check if the values from the textboxes are valid.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to just replace the `TextBox` controls with a `DateTimePicker` or equivalent, depending on what platform you're developing on. Converting strings to dates or vice-versa is more of a pain than it seems at first.

---

Or you could try using `DateTime.ParseExact` instead, to specify the exact expected format:

```
DateTime tempDateBorrowed =
    DateTime.ParseExact("3/17/2014", "M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

Or you could specify a specific culture in the call to `DateTime.Parse`:

```
var tempDateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("17/3/2014", new CultureInfo("en-gb"));

var tempDateBorrowed = DateTime.Parse("3/17/2014", new CultureInfo("en-us"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try formatting your date to iso 8601 or something like that before parsing it with DateTime.Parse.

2014-03-17T00:00:00 should work with DateTime.Parse. ("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDateBorrowed.Text, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDateBorrowed))
{
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Today - tempDateBorrowed;
}
```